# set CSS properties of an ember-view div

Tags: javascript, html, css, ember.js

I've set the height of the `<body>` tag in my ember application to `100vh`.
Now inside my `application/template.hbs`, I have a root `<div>` in there.
I'm unable to set the height of this root `<div>` to `100vh` because when the application is finally rendered, the dom is as follows:

```
<body>
    This is 100% of viewport
    <div id="ember435" class="ember-view">
        This div was automatically generated by ember, and I can't change its height. :/
        <div id="wrapper">This is my div and not 100% of body</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: What is the problem with adding a CSS with .ember-view { height: 100%; } ?

Comment: All views in ember have `ember-view` class. This will cause all those views to be 100%. I don't think I'd want that,

Comment: If you have multiple views, you can always apply an additional specific class to any view to distinguish if from the others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.ember-view` will be included for all ember component by default. so you can try the below

```
body > .ember-view{
  height : 100%;
}
```

Refer for information. https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/11486

Comment: I guess, yours is the only solution to go with.

Answer (score 0):

You can define insertion point of the app.

```
//index.html
<body>
    {{content-for "body"}}

    <script src="{{rootURL}}assets/vendor.js"></script>
    <script src="{{rootURL}}assets/client-web-ember.js"></script>

    <div id="my-app"></div>

    {{content-for "body-footer"}}
  </body>
```

And in

```
// config/environment.js
ENV.APP.rootElement = '#my-app';
```

Then style anything based on the root element.